# Removing public beta failing

Tags: iphone, ios, restore, beta

Information:

- Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
- System Version: macOS 10.13.5 (17F77)
- iOS 12

Read the first: [How to remove iOS 12.0 Public Beta from iPhone 8 in order to restore archived iOS 11.4 backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329849/how-to-remove-ios-12-0-public-beta-from-iphone-8-in-order-to-restore-archived-io)

I followed the instructions under `"Problem Solved"`, but to no avail. I put my phone into recovery mode  > given the option to restore, which I did.

Unlike with other posts (e.g., https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/downgrade-ios-12-beta-3522302/ - I originally followed this one), I was not given the option to chose a backup or completely restore. Instead, it just booted up into 12 and asked me again if I wanted to install an update to connect to my computer. I don't even have the option to restore my phone to a clean backup.

Other thoughts:

- I deleted the beta profile
- I might not have backups from before 12, but then I still should be
  able to just get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

you can get a recovery iOS on the development page:

https://developer.apple.com/download/

just sign in with your appleID download the recovery image and follow this introductions:

https://wccftech.com/downgrade-ios-114-to-ios-113/

the tutorial is for iOS 11 but it's the same for iOS 12.

Please make a backup before doing this!

Edit:

at https://developer.apple.com/download/ please log in with your appleID. after that you'll see a download list:

[image]

click on see all at the entry iOS Restore Images.
You'll see another list:

[image]

Download the restore Image for your iPhone.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link you posted didn't seem to link to the actual file. I'm having trouble finding it. Could you please edit the answer?

Comment: Updated with screenshots.